How to use meta_query to retrieve posts from multiple custom post type
I am having two custom post type "meet_our_community" and "news"
I have added a checkbox field named 'add_to_meet_our_community' from the acf to 'news' post type.
Now I when tried to take all the posts from 'meet_our_community' along with the 'news' posts where the meta key 'add_to_meet_our_community' checked with value 'Yes',I am not getting result
    $args = array(
    'post_type'      => array( 'meet_our_community', 'news' ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'add_to_meet_our_community', // ACF field key for 'news' post type
            'value'   => 'Yes',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
       
    ),
     
    
);

    $combined_query = new WP_Query( $args );

Now I am getting only the correct result from the 'news'custom post only.But I need to get all the posts from 'meet_our_community' along with the news posts. how Can I add meta query that will reflect only on the news post on the WP_Query

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('meet_our_community', 'news'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
   
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'add_to_meet_our_community',
             'value' => array('Yes'),
            'compare' => 'LIKE', 
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'add_to_meet_our_community',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'date',
    'orderby' => array('date' => 'DESC')
);

this code worked for me

Your query there is looking for results from either post type that have the meta value. AFAIK there's no way to do that in a single query unless you also add the checkbox to the other post type.

I just need to add the meta query for news post only and get all the posts from 'add_to_meet_our_community' posts. is there any way  get it. I am still stuck on it

Like I said, you could add the checkbox to meet_our_community. Or you could run two queries, one for meet_our_community and one for news with the checkbox and merge the results.

nice to meet you and thanks for the help.
yes. there is an option to run two query's  and merge it. But the the requirement I am facing it to in single query, but the meta query not working as expected.else i need to move for sql query.
still the meta query  'And' condition is been added to the 'meet_our_community' post that result the issue. Can't able to getting the thing figure out.
